# f.readline() != '0' even if reading a line containing only 0

Tags: python, file, readline

I do not have trouble setting variables in the program with the `var = f.readline()` function, but I am having trouble with the `if` statement when it comes to reading out of a text file. I am trying to see if a 0 is in a text file and every time I use the `if f.readline() == '0':` it acts as if it does not equal 0.

Example of my script below:

```
f = open("file.txt","r")

myvar = f.readline()
f.close



if myvar == "0":
    print "The variable is 0"
    raw_input("Press enter to continue")
else:
    print "The variable is not 0"
    raw_input("Press enter to continue")
```

My code would come out as `The variable is not 0`

Why is this? And how can I use an `if` statement with the `readline` function?

Comment: What about a `print(repr(myvar))` at the right place? It would help you understand what happens...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `readline` method does not remove trailing newlines from lines.  You need to do this manually:

```
myvar = f.readline().rstrip()
```

Otherwise, `myvar` will be equal to `"0\n"`, which is not equal to `"0"`.

---

Also, you forgot to close the file by calling the `close` method:

```
f.close() # Notice the parenthesis
```

Of course, using a [with-statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) would be better:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    myvar = f.readline().rstrip()
```

`with` will automatically close the file when control leaves its code block.

Comment: Thanks! I struggled with this for a little bit. I really appreciate it. Thanks for the fast reply.